# ceilometer api giving an error : 'str' object is not callable

Tags: api, openstack

I have to use the ceilometer api and whenever I type

```
root@osgrizzly:~# ceilometer meter-list
'str' object is not callable
```

I am not sure why is this error coming and what should i do to solve it. I googled it but still no answer, Can somebody please help me....

To tell about this system . I am manually installing ceilometer.
Also the compute ,collector and central agents are running fine and feeding data to mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Ensure that the username password you are using in ceilometerclient/shell.py is correct.